# Bash script to run development tasks for configured projects

Tags: bash

I wrote this script template at work to save typing repetitive commands and to improve my Bash-fu. I'd like to know of any moderate-to-severe quoting, robustness, security or usability issue. All code provided in answers should work in Bash 4.

---

**.sedevrc:**

```
#!/bin/bash
se_projects=()
se_cvs_dir="${USER}@172.0.0.1/export/home/cvsrootdir"
#============PROJECT CONFIG START================#
declare -A product
product[CVSROOT]="${se_cvs_dir}/product"
product[SOURCEDIR]="${HOME}/product"
product[WORKDIR]="${HOME}/test"
product[MAINPRG]="${product[SOURCEDIR]}/build/product"
se_projects+=("${!product@}")
#================================================#
# Other products in the same format as above
#=============PROJECT CONFIG END=================#

# se user commands
function secvs
{
    se_loop_projects "_se_cvs" "$@"
}

function sectags
{
    se_loop_projects "_se_ctags" "$@"
}

function semake
{
    se_loop_projects "_se_make" "$@"
}

function sealias
{
    se_loop_projects "_se_alias" "$@"
}

# se helper functions
function _se_cvs
{
    echo_info "Updating ${project}..."
    local cvsroot=${project}[CVSROOT]
    CVSROOT=:pserver:${!cvsroot:?}
    local sourcedir=${project}[SOURCEDIR]
    cd ${!sourcedir:?}
    cvs -q update -Pd && echo_noerror "Update ${project} complete" || echo_error "Update ${project} failed"
}

function _se_ctags
{
    echo_info "Tagging ${project}..."
    local sourcedir=${project}[SOURCEDIR]
    cd ${!sourcedir:?}/src
    { file tags | grep 'Ctags tag' >/dev/null; } || rm -f tags
    ctags -R --exclude=obj && echo_noerror "Tag ${project} complete" || echo_error "Tag ${project} failed"
}

function _se_make
{
    echo_info "Building ${project}..."
    local sourcedir=${project}[SOURCEDIR]
    cd ${!sourcedir:?}
    if [[ -d build ]] && (( $(bc <<< "$(date +%s) - $(date -r build +%s)") > 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 ))
    then
        make clean || echo_error "Clean ${project} failed"
    fi
    make && echo_noerror "Build ${project} complete" || echo_error "Build ${project} failed"
}

function _se_alias
{
    local workdir=${project}[WORKDIR]
    local mainprg=${project}[MAINPRG]
    alias ${project}="cd ${!workdir:?} && ${!mainprg:?}"
}

# Run an se helper function over selected projects
function se_loop_projects
{
    local helper_function_name=$(declare -F $1)
    if [[ ! ${helper_function_name} =~ ^_se_* ]]
    then
        echo_error "'$1' is not in the list of available se helper functions: $(declare -F | cut -d' ' -f3 | grep '^_se_*' | xargs)"
        if [[ -z $1 ]]
        then
            echo_error "Usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]} FUNCTION [PROJECTS]"
        fi
        return 1
    fi
    shift
    local -i project_count=$(( $# > 0 && $# < ${#se_projects[@]} ? $# : ${#se_projects[@]} ))
    for (( i=0; i<${project_count}; i++ ))
    do
        local project=${1:-${se_projects[$i]:?}}
        shift
        if [[ ${se_projects[@]} =~ ${project} ]]
        then
            local helper_function=helper_function_name
            if [[ ${helper_function_name} == '_se_alias' ]] # FIXME: hardcoding
            then
                ${!helper_function} # Safer than `eval '"${helper_function}"'`
            else
                set -e
                (${!helper_function}) &
                set +e
            fi
        else
            local IFS=','
            echo_warning "'${project}' is not in the list of available se projects: ${se_projects[*]}"
        fi
    done
    wait
    while (( $# > 0 ))
    do
        echo_warning "Too many arguments, omitting '$1'"
        shift
    done
}

# Customized echoes
echo_reset_color=$(tput sgr0)

function echo_info
{
    local echo_info_color=$(tput setaf 4) # Blue
    echo "${echo_info_color}$@${echo_reset_color}"
}

function echo_noerror
{
    local echo_noerror_color=$(tput setaf 2) # Green
    echo "${echo_noerror_color}$@${echo_reset_color}"
}

function echo_warning
{
    local echo_warning_color=$(tput setaf 3) # Orange
    >&2 echo "${echo_warning_color}$@${echo_reset_color}"
}

function echo_error
{
    local echo_error_color=$(tput setaf 1) # Red
    >&2 echo "${echo_error_color}$@${echo_reset_color}"
}

# Autocomplete project names for se user commands
complete -W "${se_projects[*]}" $(declare -F | cut -d' ' -f3 | grep '^se[a-z]\+' | xargs)
```

---

To run it interactively,

```
[gao@hostname ~]-bash4.1.2$ secvs product1
[1] 16516
Updating product1...
? src/hello.cc
M Makefile
Update product1 complete
[1]+  Done                    ( ${!helper_function} )
[gao@hostname ~]-bash4.1.2$ secvs hats product1 stackoverflow
'hats' is not in the list of available se projects: product1,product2
[1] 16590
Updating product1...
M Makefile
Update product1 complete
[1]+  Done                    ( ${!helper_function} )
Too many arguments, omitting 'stackoverflow'
[gao@hostname ~]-bash4.1.2$ sectags
[1] 16519
Tagging product2...
[2] 16520
Tagging product1...
Tag product1 complete
Tag product2 complete
[1]-  Done                    ( ${!helper_function} )
[2]+  Done                    ( ${!helper_function} )
```

To run it via crontab,

```
[gao@hostname ~]-bash4.1.2$ cat ~/cronjob
#!/bin/bash
# Nullify commands that would trigger unwanted mail notification when run by cron
function echo { return; }
function tput { return; }

# Run se user commands
source "${HOME}/.sedevrc"
secvs | grep '^C ' # Show only conflicts
sectags
semake >/dev/null
[gao@hostname ~]-bash4.1.2$ crontab -l
7 7 * * 1-5 ${HOME}/cronjob
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Use the correct form for associative arrays

The code contains this line:

```
local cvsroot=${project}[CVSROOT]
```

But I am pretty sure that what was meant was this:

```
local cvsroot=${project[CVSROOT]}
```

### Quote to prevent word splitting

This line needs quotes to prevent word splitting:

```
cd ${!sourcedir:?}
```

If the contents of `sourcedir` contains a path with an embedded space, the `cd` will fail.  Add quotes to prevent this problem:

```
cd "${!sourcedir:?}"
```

The same issue exists for the last clause of the `complete` function.

### Use `|| exit` if a command fails

If the `cd` command mentioned above actually fails, the script will proceed anyway and this is unlikely to be desired.  Instead, you could use this:

```
cd "${!sourcedir:?}" || exit 1
```

### Use `if-else` if you need that functionality

One of the lines in the current code is this:

```
ctags -R --exclude=obj && echo_noerror "Tag ${project} complete" || echo_error "Tag ${project} failed"
```

The intent appears to be to print one string or the other depending on the outcome of the `ctags` program.  However, be aware that the *second* message might be printed even if `ctags` runs without error.  This is because `echo_noerror` might fail and then the `echo_error` function would be invoked.  To make the code more robust, don't use this trick.  Instead, use the plain old `if-else` construct:

```
if ctags -R --exclude=obj; then echo_noerror "Tag ${project} complete"; else echo_error "Tag ${project} failed"; fi
```

Or as I'd probably prefer formatting it:

```
if ctags -R --exclude=obj 
then 
    echo_noerror "Tag ${project} complete" 
else 
    echo_error "Tag ${project} failed"
fi
```

### Understand the use of numeric variables

In this context:

```
for (( i=0; i<${project_count}; i++ ))
```

The `${}` is not needed because it's a numeric variable.  Instead, just write this:

```
for (( i=0; i<project_count; i++ ))
```

### Don't mix string and array

In this line

```
echo "${echo_noerror_color}$@${echo_reset_color}"
```

The colors expand to strings, but the `$@` is an array.  To make it a string, use this instead:

```
echo "${echo_noerror_color}$*${echo_reset_color}"
```

There's more, but it's all I have time for at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. 1. I was using indirect reference for associative arrays, so `${!sourcedir}` actually refers to `${product[SOURCEDIR]}`. 2. If I enclose the last clause of the `complete` function in double quotes (single quotes would simply be wrong), running `complete -p` shows `complete -W 'product1 product2' sealias sectags secvs semake` in one line which doesn't autocomplete project names, whereas what I've posted would print four `complete` statements each with an se user command that does autocomplete.

Comment: 3. There is no need to add `|| exit` as I've added `set -e` before running the se helper function, the effect of which is that the process will stop executing after any simple statement returns a non-zero exit code. 4. You are right, but I've found a way to avoid writing `if-else` or `&&-||` and which further reduces code duplication. Maybe I'll post it as an answer on Monday. 2., 5. & 6. Advice taken. Thank you for teaching me new things and improving my understanding of Bash.